# When can a principle $G$-bundle over the boundary be extended into the bulk?

Tags: fiber-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $M$ be an $m$-dimensional smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$, and let $G$ be a compact Lie group. When can a principal $G$-bundle with base manifold $\partial M$ be extended to a principal $G$-bundle with base manifold $M$?

If the general answer is unknown, then where can I find a good review of partial results?

I have a superficial/physics-level familiarity with the ideas of homotopy groups, classifying spaces, and bordisms, but I'm not yet fluent enough in the languages of topology to know exactly how to apply those ideas to this question.

Comment: If $f$ denotes the classifying map of the principal $G$-bundle on $\partial M$, then a necessary condition for $f$ to extend to $M$ is that the element $[(\partial M, f)] \in \Omega_{m-1}(BG)$ vanishes. However, this just tells you that $\partial M$ bounds some manifold which admits a principal $G$-bundle which extends the given one, but this manifold may not be $M$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you for the comment! Even though the question specified $M$, I am also interested in the existence of any $M$ admitting a principal $G$-bundle that extends the one on "$\partial M$," so I am very interested in your comment. I'm not familiar with the notation $[(\partial M,f)]$ and $\Omega_{m-1}(BG)$, but I'm guessing that $[(\partial M,f)]$ is something like an equivalence class of maps $f:\partial M\to BG$. Is that on the right track? I can post the unspecified-$M$ version as a separate question if that would be better.

Comment: You're pretty much on the right track. This is known as [singular bordism](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/B-Bordism#Singular_bordism).